# Is Using many anonymous objects with many firebase tasks as listener will show affect on the memory?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase-Firestore as my backend server for my shop app, if I am going to use the get method with many Document References to download many sets of data and I am adding OnSuccessListener for each task. So I will have many listeners, is this will increase the app memory??

[My method with this operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olrpv.png)

code Text

```
private void loadShopProductByQuery() {
    for (Shop shop : shops) {
        String shopId = shop.getShopId();
        fireStore.collection(applicationContext.getString(R.string.products_collection))
                .whereEqualTo(applicationContext.getString(R.string.shop_ID_field_product_document), shopId).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(poolExecutor, queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    List<Product> shopProducts = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                        Product product = documentSnapshot.toObject(Product.class);
                        Objects.requireNonNull(product).setProductID(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        shopProducts.add(product);
                    }
                    shop.setProductList(shopProducts);
                    oneShop.postValue(shop);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: loadShopProductsByQuery e:" + e.getLocalizedMessage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for messy, this is my first question here.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Android, or Firebase - not really. It may impact an Android device with lower memory (though most modern phones have more than enough memory to deal with the question your asking), but the core of your question is just about basic Java. I recommend adjusting your question to ask the core of your question: `do anonymous classes impact memory?` is basically what you just asked. Though I'm not going to directly answer, the basic answer is `no more than any other compiled Java class.`

Comment: I have passed OnSuccessListener as lambda expression and this code will be repeat for each for loop. So is this code will saved each time. I mean is lambda expression still reference object for the OnSuccessListener @searchengine27

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have any "listeners" here at all.  You have a query, executed with `get()`.  Of course, you should expect that if you hold the results of a query in memory, that each new query will take up more memory.  There is really no way to know for sure what is too much.  You should estimate how much you need based on the documents you are querying.  But unless you are querying for and storing hundreds of thousands of documents, you probably won't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to highlight something my OnSuccessListener expressed in lambda expression. I am just concern if this code is will be saved for each for loop rather than the documents query.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "saved".  When the query is complete, everything will be garbage collected when your code is done.

Comment: The OnSuccessListener that I am using here is in lambda expression, is the reference listener (In lambda or not) that will be repeated many times will all saved on the memory or it will be removed?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  It will be garbage collected when the task is complete and no longer needed.